# How to get rid of the following error with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

When I am running the following code with `data.txt` file...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
            \pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\Rtable
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={mu},
    ylabel={f},
    xmin=3, xmax=50,
    ymin=50, ymax=100,
    legend style={at={(axis cs:50,80)},anchor=south east,font=\tiny},
    legend entries={$\eta=0.5$, $\eta=1.5$, $\eta=2.5$,$\eta=5$,$\eta=10$,$\eta=15$,$\eta=25$}
    ]
    \addplot[color=magenta,mark=o,mark color=green] table[y = Eta05] from \Rtable ;
    \addplot[color=teal,mark=square,mark color=green] table[y = Eta105] from \Rtable ; 
    \addplot[color=green,mark=*,mark color=green] table[y = Eta205] from \Rtable ; 
    \addplot[color=blue,mark=star,mark color=green] table[y = Eta5] from \Rtable ; 
    \addplot[color=cyan,mark=otimes,mark color=green] table[y = Eta10] from \Rtable ; 
    \addplot[color=red,mark=triangle,mark color=green] table[y = Eta15] from \Rtable ; 
    \addplot[color=orange,mark=x,mark color=green] table[y = Eta25] from \Rtable ; 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I encounter with the error:

```
    Package pgfplots Error: Table 'data.txt' appears to have too many coly.
 Also verify that column names are plain ASCII.).
 This error is not critical. ...pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\Rtable
    Dimension too large. \end{axis}
    Dimension too large. \end{axis}
    running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features).
 Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} into your preamble.
```

After adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` in my preamble, still I got the following error

```
Package pgfplots Error: Table 'data.txt' appears to have too many coly. 
Also verify that column names are plain ASCII.). This error is not critical.
 ...pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\Rtable
Dimension too large. \end{axis}
Dimension too large. \end{axis}
Dimension too large. \end{axis}
```

But when I added

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    mu & Eta05   & Eta105  & Eta205    & Eta5      & Eta10     & Eta15     & Eta25     
2.5& 158.086810& 148.218338& 141.185738& 132.213683& 123.803119 &117.787777 &108.482610 
3.0& 98.451835& 87.054289& 79.628072& 72.106007& 68. 486806& 67.002723& 65.169244  
3.5& 85.401668& 74.166957& 67.125917& 60.992210& 59.808002& 59.948999  & 60.051464  
4.0& 80.752934& 69.614034& 62.786944& 57.414396& 57.387458  & 58.159165  & 58.879482  
4.5& 78.649980& 67.543726& 60.832928& 55.909321& 56.508328& 57.571088  & 58.532668  
5.0& 77.574273& 66.465392& 59.817595& 55.176014& 56.147092  & 57.360550  & 58.427176  
5.5& 76.983310& 65.852998& 59.238120& 54.782912  & 55.991561& 57.289748  & 58.404536  
6.0& 76.644634& 65.483328& 58.883928& 54.557119  & 55.926289& 57.275203  & 58.412101  
6.5& 76.446290& 65.249637& 58.655427& 54.420231  & 55.902972& 57.283827  & 58.430182  
7.5& 76.262599& 64.992702& 58.393061& 54.276059  & 55.905690& 57.321824  & 58.471161  
8.5& 76.208315& 64.869417& 58.255500& 54.208693& 55.927382& 57.360911  & 58.506102  
9.5& 76.204858& 64.804256& 58.173757& 54.172047& 55.949867& 57.393085  & 58.532877  
10.0& 76.211650& 64.783063& 58.144280& 54.159353& 55.959829  & 57.406375  & 58.543584  
11.5& 76.244573& 64.742614& 58.080603 & 54.132025& 55.983407& 57.436788  & 58.567443  
13.5& 76.292395& 64.713241& 58.025281  & 54.106536  & 56.002348  & 57.461302  & 58.586027  
15   & 76.323304& 64.698158  & 57.994336  & 54.090627  & 56.010017  & 57.472000  & 58.593899  
20   & 76.391403& 64.660545  & 57.919966  & 54.046219  & 56.015134  & 57.484401  & 58.602444  
25   & 76.424631& 64.630563  & 57.868278  & 54.010977  & 56.008094  & 57.482538  & 58.600464  
30   & 76.440877& 64.605689  & 57.829598  & 53.982983  & 55.998462  & 57.476841  & 58.595800  
40   & 76.452460& 64.568135  & 57.776076  & 53.942674  & 55.980506  & 57.464379  & 58.585989  
50   & 76.454123& 64.542162  & 57.741491  & 53.915912  & 55.966629  & 57.454055  & 58.577986 
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{data.csv}{\Rtable}
```

in the preamble, its working fine. What was the problem with my initial code?

Comment: What is the column separator in `data.txt`?

Comment: No separator, only a tab space.

Comment: It's because you have an extra space in row 2 in column `Eta10` (`68. 486806`). To solve this, include `[col sep=tab]` in `\pgfplotstableread` or simply remove the extra space. With the initial setting of `col sep=space` both tabs and spaces are considered column separators, making the second row of data have one extra column (it interprets `68.` as one column and `486806` as another), which raises the error you are getting.

Comment: Also, consider updating `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable` to the latest versions.

Comment: Even if the extra space was there my second code is working perfectly. Removing that extra space in my `data.txt` produces no error in case of the first code.

Comment: That's because you specify the column separator `&` in the second example, which makes the parser ignore whitespaces. Since you didn't specify `col sep=tab` in the first code, `col sep=space` is used, and this interprets _any_ whitespace (except line feeds) as column separators, giving you an extra column.

Comment: @hooy can you write an answer please ?

Comment: @percusse Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation of the error

In the second row of your data (excluding headings) in the column labeled `Eta10` you have an extra space in the entry `68. 486806`.

Since you didn't specify `col sep` in the `\pgfplotstableread` command, the initial value is used, i.e. `col sep=space`. This setting conciders both spaces and tabs (actually, *any* whitespace except linefeeds) as column separators, giving you one extra column in this row; `68.` is concidered one column and `486806` another. This raises the error you are getting.

#### Possible solutions

To solve this, you can:

1. simply remove the extra space in the `data.txt` file.
2. provide `col sep=tab`, which is a more flexible solution if there are multiple occurences of such misformatted input, since this will only concider tabs to be column separators.Thus,

   ```
   \pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab]{data.txt}\Rtable
   ```

   should make your code work.